# Can I temporally block a duct trunk to only heat part of my home?

Tags: hvac

I live in the basement and I only occasionally use the upstairs. I don't want to heat the rest of the house most of the time. I'm contemplating installing retractable diverters on the trunk that feed the rest of the house so hot air just goes into the basement (past the single vent that feeds the basement).

I can't seem to find any commercial diverters for the trunk. I was thinking something stupidly simple like cutting a small 1cm slot in the trunk bottom (right below the joist) and putting a sliding panel of plywood that I can block it off when needed, right near the plenum. When I need to open it up, just cover the slot with tape.

Any issues with that plan?

Comment: Have you searched for "damper"? I found several options quickly using that term, many of which are suitable for trunk use. I'd be concerned about moisture content with your wood panel idea, maybe if you seal/paint it. I use a humidifier during the winter so wood may be fine if you don't have moist air.

Comment: "I do not believe there is any return from the basement itself." - "Are there issues with return still being from rest of the house?" - cut a hole in the return chamber and put a register (that you can close, not a return grill).  If it still trips out on overheat *then* the answer to the title is no. Put sharpie, *remove for summer -->*.  It'd be better if it was the size of the duct, sheet metal, with a 1/2" bend on the bottom, screwed in. Tape the slot anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zone heating is a great philosophy for saving money in a building. You want to still heat the main part of the house enough to drive out moisture from the structure, but you don't need to heat it to totally comfortable. This plan, though, has some issues.

The biggest issue with this plan is that your heating system is likely to be dramatically oversized for just the basement. This will result in two effects:

1. Depending on the design of the equipment, you run the risk of damaging it. High levels of backpressure can cause premature blower failure, heat exchanger overtemperature, poor efficiency, and other issues. When you remove most of the ducting from use you will dramatically increase backpressure at the same flow level.
2. Your system will probably end up 'short cycling' which can be very inefficient, as the startup part of the cycle is the least efficient part of operation. It might also result in poor comfort, and of course if your thermostat is located upstairs, temperature control could be quite bad.

Both of these issues are less likely to happen if you have a two-stage or variable speed air handler, since those will both be configured to work well at lower flow, and more likely to spend all their time running at lower speeds. That doesn't totally eliminate the risk, just mitigate it.

Additionally to the above, you'll likely end up with really noisy vents, because you'll be trying to force a whole house full of air through a few basement vents. If your basement does not have a return (many don't) all of the above will be even worse.

Instead, consider leaving the system balanced as normal, but setting back the temperature to something like 62F. Then add supplemental heat in the areas where you're living. Supplemental heat could be as simple as an electric space heater, or as complicated as adding a gas fireplace or a mini-split heat pump to the basement area. Cheaper options like space heaters will cost less up front but more in long term energy usage. More expensive options like a gas fireplace or mini-split heat pump will cost more up front but much less in energy across time. If the house is much bigger than the basement, and the basement is decently insulated and air sealed, an electric space heater can still be very cost efficient.

An approach like this can work really well. I was in a similar situation in my last house, and I ended up adding a mini-split to the basement. It worked great, and my heating costs were very low given the size of the house. Once the furnace failed due to age, I ended up adding a zoned mini-split to the main house, and it worked really well also, letting me just heat the parts of the house that needed it. The up front investment though was significant, so the payback period after offsetting the cost of a replacement furnace was about ten years.

Oh: and in addition to all the above, technically this requires a mechanical permit in most places, as it's a modification. The inspector won't like your DIY approach to making a blast gate or damper. They are a commercial product available in all sizes.

Comment: Follow up question

I have a space heater (electric fireplace), but when I tried measuring it's energy consumption it was a whooping 5kwh, which would run me $250/month. Same as heating the whole house. 

I have a 2 way split from the plenum that goes to the rest of the house, one of them has a smaller vent into the basement. I do not believe their is any return from the basement itself. If I add a third trunk size channel to the basement and close off the other two, I don't believe there would be back pressure. Is there issues with return still being from rest of the house?

Comment: Oh and thermostat is already repositioned into basement area.

Comment: First: if you're in the US your electric fireplace doesn't use 5kW. If it plugs in to a normal wall outlet, it uses 1.5kW or less. If your basement has decent insulation, it also won't run all the time, but will start cycling once you're to temperature. Second: maybe. You'll need a return in the basement, you'll need significant changes to the ducting, and it's still quite likely that your furnace will be substantially oversized for the application.

Comment: And if you're mixing up kW and kWh it will be hard to calculate costs. kWh is energy used across time, kW is instantaneous power usage.

Comment: Probably not an issue, but if you have any water lines under pressure - especially near an exterior wall, they need to either run slowly or be heated lest they break and give you a really bad day. Not terribly likely you have a kitchen or bathroom upstairs that will get below freezing, but it's definitely worth looking at.